# Only copy items in document library that exist in notepad list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I  trying to find a way to export files for different document library depending on notepad list provided. All document library URL are in the notepad.

Need this in powershell

Answer (score 0):

As the URLs are in the notepad, you can use [Get-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1) to read the content. Are you using SharePoint Online or on-premise? For SharePoint Online, you can try script [here](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/09/sharepoint-online-download-file-from-library-using-powershell.html).

For On-Prem version, you can take a look at this:https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2014/02/download-file-from-sharepoint-using.html